# org.springframework.data.cassandra.CassandraUncategorizedException

Tags: java, spring-boot, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I'm using a hibernate in the spring boot to call the method `findByIdField(UUID id)` in Cassandra 3.11 to return a list and this erro bellow appear in the console log.

I have a *entity*, *repository* and *service* with this simple method. I'm passing a UUID as parameter and I check the ID in the database and it exist.

Controller :

```
Optional<List<Fields>> fieldList = fieldService.findByIdField(UUID.fromString(id));
```

Service :

```
public Optional<List<Fields>> findByIdField(UUID id) throws SQLException {
    return repository.findByIdField(id);
}
```

Repository:

```
@AllowFiltering
Optional<List<Fields>> findByIdField(UUID id);
```

Error:

> org.springframework.data.cassandra.CassandraUncategorizedException: nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.CassandraExceptionTranslator.translate(CassandraExceptionTranslator.java:160) ~[spring-data-cassandra-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
> at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.CassandraExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(CassandraExceptionTranslator.java:72) ~[spring-data-cassandra-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
> at org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.CqlSessionFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(CqlSessionFactoryBean.java:646) ~[spring-data-cassandra-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
> at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61) ~[spring-tx-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242) ~[spring-tx-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152) ~[spring-tx-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy117.findByIdSensor(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
> at br.com.genesis.service.operacao.GerarStatusSinalSasMcsScmPiService.findByIdSensor(GerarStatusSinalSasMcsScmPiService.java:44) ~[classes/:2.4.2]
> at br.com.genesis.controller.operacao.OpeStatusComponeteController.mostraHistoricoFalha(OpeStatusComponeteController.java:941) ~[classes/:2.4.2]
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
> at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197) ~[spring-web-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141) ~[spring-web-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1060) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:962) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652) ~[servlet-api.jar:4.0.FR]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[servlet-api.jar:4.0.FR]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [catalina.jar:9.0.41]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.41]
> at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-websocket.jar:9.0.41]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.41]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.41]
> at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.41]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.41]
> at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.41]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.41]
> at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:126) [spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
> at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:64) [spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
> at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:101) [spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:119) [spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.41]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.41]
> at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) [spring-web-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:9.0.41]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:9.0.41]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) [catalina.jar:9.0.41]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) [catalina.jar:9.0.41]
> at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) [catalina.jar:9.0.41]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) [catalina.jar:9.0.41]
> at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [catalina.jar:9.0.41]
> at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690) [catalina.jar:9.0.41]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) [catalina.jar:9.0.41]
> at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [catalina.jar:9.0.41]
> at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.41]
> at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.41]
> at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:888) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.41]
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1597) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.41]
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-coyote.jar:9.0.41]
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_152]
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_152]
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:9.0.41]
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_152]
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
> at sun.invoke.util.ValueConversions.unboxLong(ValueConversions.java:121) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
> at br.com.genesis.model.entity.operacao.GerarStatusSinalSasMcsScmPi_Accessor_7l4hif.setProperty(Unknown Source) ~[classes/:2.4.2]
> at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.InstantiationAwarePropertyAccessor.setProperty(InstantiationAwarePropertyAccessor.java:104) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
> at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.ConvertingPropertyAccessor.setProperty(ConvertingPropertyAccessor.java:63) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
> at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.convert.MappingCassandraConverter.readProperty(MappingCassandraConverter.java:413) ~[spring-data-cassandra-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
> at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.convert.MappingCassandraConverter.readProperties(MappingCassandraConverter.java:400) ~[spring-data-cassandra-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
> at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.convert.MappingCassandraConverter.doReadEntity(MappingCassandraConverter.java:389) ~[spring-data-cassandra-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
> at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.convert.MappingCassandraConverter.doReadEntity(MappingCassandraConverter.java:365) ~[spring-data-cassandra-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
> at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.convert.MappingCassandraConverter.readEntityFromRow(MappingCassandraConverter.java:345) ~[spring-data-cassandra-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
> at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.convert.MappingCassandraConverter.readRow(MappingCassandraConverter.java:341) ~[spring-data-cassandra-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
> at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.convert.MappingCassandraConverter.read(MappingCassandraConverter.java:298) ~[spring-data-cassandra-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
> at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate.lambda$getMapper$11(CassandraTemplate.java:910) ~[spring-data-cassandra-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
> at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate.lambda$select$0(CassandraTemplate.java:337) ~[spring-data-cassandra-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
> at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:83) ~[spring-data-cassandra-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
> at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:43) ~[spring-data-cassandra-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
> at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.CqlTemplate.query(CqlTemplate.java:298) ~[spring-data-cassandra-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
> at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.CqlTemplate.query(CqlTemplate.java:320) ~[spring-data-cassandra-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
> at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate.select(CassandraTemplate.java:337) ~[spring-data-cassandra-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
> at org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.query.CassandraQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.execute(CassandraQueryExecution.java:136) ~[spring-data-cassandra-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
> at org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.query.CassandraQueryExecution$ResultProcessingExecution.execute(CassandraQueryExecution.java:262) ~[spring-data-cassandra-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
> at org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.query.AbstractCassandraQuery.execute(AbstractCassandraQuery.java:105) ~[spring-data-cassandra-3.1.3.jar:3.1.3]
> at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
> at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
> at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:152) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
> at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:131) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
> at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
> at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy117.findByIdSensor(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
> at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) ~[spring-aop-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
> ... 63 common frames omitted

Comment: Just curious, but what happens when you remove `@AllowFiltering` from the repository code?  That's not something what should ever be in a production application.

Comment: When I remove the `@AllowFiltering`, the spring boot framework return this message : `Query; CQL [com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.DefaultSimpleStatement@d8a9e7d1]; Cannot execute this query as it might involve data filtering and thus may have unpredictable performance. If you want to execute this query despite the performance unpredictability, use ALLOW FILTERING; `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the error message indicates a NPE (null pointer exception), I think that's masking the root problem here.  However, the error message displayed when removing `ALLOW FILTERING`:

```
Cannot execute this query as it might involve
data filtering and thus may have unpredictable
performance. If you want to execute this query
despite the performance unpredictability, use
ALLOW FILTERING;
```

...is much more revealing.

This tells me that the underlying table is not keyed by the UUID.  This means that Cassandra has to scan all partitions on each node (exhaustively) to build the result set.  It probably works in cqlsh because the query timeout threshold is set higher than Spring's.

As for how to resolve this, I'll recommend that a new table be created to support this query, with a partition key based on that UUID.  That will prevent every node from being a part of the query.

If that's not possible to do, you could try adding a secondary index on that column.  Secondary indexes don't typically perform well with nigh-unique cardinality (which is why building a new table is really the best option), but it would probably perform better than using the `ALLOW FILTERING` directive.

Comment: Thank you! That was the point. I'll try to create a new table.